# Logon web site using button.click

Tags: watin

I want to use watin simulating a logon process. I use

```
browser.Button(Find.ByClass("button")).Click();
```

It worked several times, then it stopped working. I can see the page refreshed but I wasn't logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Firefox works better in my environment. IE is not very reliable. However you have to use Firefox 4.3. Good news is that you can use portable Firefox.